# Enabling AD account using powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

All the new user accounts created in Active Directory are kept as disabled and the option "user must change password on next login" is ticked. This accounts will remain as disabled for 7 days and in the 8th day it needs to be enabled.. Creating the account is already done by another script and I am stuck with account enable part.

How can I archive enabling these account using PowerShell script? How to use all account properties like lastlogon date, account creation date, account status(disabled), and the option "user must change  password on next login" to validate and find the user is a new user which needs to enable?

```
get-aduser -f {-not ( lastlogontimestamp -like "*") -and (enabled -eq $false) -and (pwdLastSet -eq 0)} | 
    Select-Object name,SamAccountName | 
    export-csv -path data.csv
```

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service; it's expected that you've attempted your own solution and you need help fixing it.

Comment: The command i tried is given below, but this cant check the user is already passed 7 days of disable period.. 
    get-aduser -f {-not ( lastlogontimestamp -like "*") -and (enabled -eq $false) -and (pwdLastSet -eq 0)} | Select-Object name,SamAccountName | export-csv -path data.csv

Comment: OK, so you've shown how you're puling the data, but what have you done WRT attempting to use it as you described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use filters to filter according to your criteria.  This snippet gets user objects for accounts that are disabled then filters out those less than a week old.  It stores them in a collection of user objects.  You can further filter $userlist by any user object property using the `$variable | $variable where { [filter] }` format.  The filters can be as complex as you want.  I like putting one on each line so I can easily comment out given filters.  Use the filtered list for whatever you want.

```
$WeekAgoDate = $(Get-Date).addDays(-7)

$userlist = get-aduser -filter { enabled -eq $false } -Properties *
$userlist = $userlist | Where { $_.created -lt $WeekAgoDate }
"$userlist.count accounts found"
$userlist | select name, samaccountname | format-table
```

To enable $userlist:
    $userlist | Enable-ADAccount

Comment: `Get-ADUser -filter {(enabled -eq $false) -and (pwdLastSet -eq 0) -  and -not (lastlogontimestamp -like "*")} -Properties whencreated | Where-Object { $_.whencreated -gt (get-date).adddays(-7) } | select name,SamAccountName,whenCreated | export-csv -path data.csv -NoTypeInformation`

The Above command works well to collect the user information.. But if i need to communicate over LDAP, how i need to change this code..? I'm totally new to this .. :(

Comment: I'm not experienced with LDAP.  I know you can use -LDAPFilter instead of -Filter when you use Get-ADUser.  Are you saying you need to run this against a different domain?  The method you used in the other comment, building an LDAP searcher, is done for Powershell v1 or v2 without access to ActiveDirectory Powershell module.  

In general terms, what do you need to do with the userlist once you've pulled it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it but you will need to write the script:

Check the `whenCreated` attribute It has a date time stamp and you can use that to see how old the account is.

If the account is older then 7 days and the account is disabled set the `userAccountControl` attribute to enabled IE `512` and then set your user must change password property true

Comment: If you are just leading the OP then this would serve better as a comment.

Comment: Is Anybody can help me to elaborate this.. As i mentioned earlier i am totaly new to this.. :(

$Domain = "dc=XYZ,dc=ABCD,dc=Domain,dc=net"
$root = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + $Domain)
$searcher=New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($root)


$searcher.Filter=”(&(samaccountname=$user))”
$results=$searcher.findone()